# python3 How to select two elements on either side of a random element in a list?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have finished this part of the code so far:

```
wedding = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
from random import randrange
random_index = randrange(0, len(wedding))
print('TV =', wedding[random_index])
```

I got stuck at a step that I need to find two elements on either side of the element that I have randomly selected.

Comment: Next time you post a question with a code sample, indent each line with 4 spaces, press the { } button, or highlight your code and press CTRL + K. This will format your code as a code sample and make it much easier to read :)

Comment: I don't get the question. What's the result supposed to look like?

Comment: Two elements on either side are `wedding[random_index-1]` and `wedding[random_index+1]` but you might get `list index out of range` error if your `random_index` is either 0, or 10.

Comment: What should happen if you randomly choose the first or last element?

Comment: I was going to answer but realized that @vishes_shell has already made most of my points. That should be enough information if you wish to fix your code:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak but it didn't stop @ PrestonM from answering.:) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When using arrays, always check for your array bounds in your code. The below code will output the value from the array that is to the left and right of the randomly selected index value. If either of the indexes are out of bounds, it will not output that value.

```
from random import randrange 

wedding = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
random_index = randrange(0, len(wedding)) 

print('TV = ', wedding[random_index])

if random_index-1 >= 0:
    print('Left of Index = ', wedding[random_index-1])
if random_index + 1 < len(wedding) - 1:
    print('Right of Index = ', wedding[random_index + 1])
```